# Renaming files using a strings from a txt file

Tags: string, powershell, filenames, rename

The question might sound confusing but all I really need is the ability to change a file name using an array of strings.

For example:

File 1 contains:
abc1234cd.jpg
abc2543ac.jpg
...

File 2 contains (array/reference)

1234c
2543a
...

The new file name for abc1234cd.jpg should now be 1234c.jpg and so forth.

Is this possible with powershell or any other language to do?

Thanks,

Comment: Are the two lists able to relate to each other?  Will 1234c only refer to a single record in file 1 (i.e., abc1234cd.jpg).  There are a number of ways to join these two objects.  People have written custom Join-Object functions that you might be able to reproduce.  But that is dependent upon the two arrays being able to match.

Comment: Actually there can be circumstance where that abc1234cd.jpg can also be abc1234cd2.jpg. I need them to be rename as 1234c.jpg and 1234c-1. 1234c-1.jpg as an increment since it contains 1234c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, assuming the files have a one-to-one match.

```
# Get contents of file 1
$File1 = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\File1.txt;
# Get contents of file 2
$File2 = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\File2.txt;

# Iterate over each item in $File1
foreach ($Item in $File1) {
    $FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\test\$Item*.jpg";
    foreach ($File in $FileList) {
        # Determine file's new name, based on corresponding value in File2
        $NewName = $File.Name -replace $Item, $File2[$File1.IndexOf($Item)];

        Write-Host -Object ('Old name: {0}, new name: {1}' -f $Item, $NewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, I was wondering if there's away to increment duplicates. EX: abc1234cd.jpg and abc1234cd2.jpg (original file) to become (1234c and 1234c-1)

Comment: Hmmmm, you'd have to do some pattern matching to achieve this. You could do a simple regex replacement on the common portion of the name: `abc1234cd`.

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours, I finally got the code to work.

```
$dir = 'file.txt'
$backup = 'C:\Users\all users\Desktop\backup'
$file = 'file2.txt'
$files =  Import-Csv -Header Name -Path $file
foreach ($line in $files){
$linefiles = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.BaseName.Contains($line.Name)}
 $count = 0
 foreach ($linefile in $linefiles) {
     #do stuff to each file here
     $name = $linefile.BaseName
     $extension = $linefile.Extension
     $newName = $line.Name

     Copy-Item -Path "$dir\$linefile" -Destination "$backup\$linefile"

     if ($count -gt 0){
       Rename-Item -NewName "$newName-$count$extension" -Path "$dir\$linefile"}
     else{
      Rename-Item -NewName "$newName$extension" -Path "$dir\$linefile"}

     $count++}
 }
```